# YouTube API V3 - Channel Required, can I programmatically create a YouTube channel?

Tags: youtube-api

The user isn't able to create a playlist unless they have a YouTube channel created on their Google account. Is there a way I can create the channel for them programmatically using JavaScript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately you can not create a new Channel (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels) in the v3 api.

One possible work around is that you redirect your end user to https://www.youtube.com/create_channel .

Comment: Thanks. That's too bad. Just frustrating to make them have to leave the web app. Makes it more likely for them to forget to come back.

Comment: The link to the developer blog is no longer active.